# Как выбросить IllegalArgumentException, если значение slot некорректно

Tags: java, исключения, методы, switch

У меня есть класс Player и в нем есть метод shotWithWeapon, нужно выбросить исключение IllegalArgumentException, если значение slot некорректно. И чтоб в методе main при вводе не правильного значения с клавиатуры выводило соответствующее исключение.

```
    public class PlayerMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Player player = new Player();

        System.out.println("Список оружии: " + "\n0.Пистолет\n1.Автомат\n2.Рпг\n3.Рогатка\n4.Водный пистолет\n");

        System.out.format("У игрока %d слотов с оружием,"
                        + " введите номер, чтобы выстрелить,"
                        + " -1 чтобы выйти:%n"
                , player.getSlotsCount()
        );

        int slot = scanner.nextInt();

        while (slot != -1) {
            switch (slot) {
                case 0:
                    player.shotWithWeapon(0);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    player.shotWithWeapon(1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    player.shotWithWeapon(2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    player.shotWithWeapon(3);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    player.shotWithWeapon(4);
                    break;
                default:

                    System.out.println("Выберите оружие от 0 до 4");
                    break;
            }
            slot = scanner.nextInt();
        }




        System.out.println("Game Over!");

    }
}
```

В классе Player нужно выбросить исключение в методе shotWithWeapon

```
public class Player {
    // Указываем тип данных Weapon, который будет храниться в "слотах игрока"

    private Weapon[] weaponSlots;

    public Player() {
        weaponSlots = new Weapon[]{
                new Pistol(),
                new MachineGun(),
                new RPG(),
                new Slingshot(),
                new WaterGun()
        };
    }

    public int getSlotsCount() {
        return weaponSlots.length;
    }

    public void shotWithWeapon(int slot)  {
        //TODO проверить на выход за границы
        // Проверить на выход за границы
        // Выбросить IllegalArgumentException, если значение slot некорректно

        Weapon weapon = weaponSlots[slot];
        weapon.shot();
    }


}
```

Comment: что является некорректным значением?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы именно через исключение хотите это делать, тогда

```
  try {
        if (slot < 0 || slot > weaponSlots.length-1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        //process exception
    }
```

Хотя зачем здесь эксепшн кидать, когда обычного if достаточно - не очень понимаю. Или это чисто учебная задачка?

Comment: Да согласен что можно вообще с if сделать, но это просто учебная задачка, спасибо за ответ благодарен!